# Adobe Creative Cloud as Document Asset Management Solution

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, adobe-bridge

Our catalog production team has requested a way to better manage images. I was curious as to what system you guys use.

We don't have it in our budget to use Adobe Experience Manager, so I've been reviewing other Document Asset Management (DAM) solutions. One I keep coming back to though, is just using bridge, but instead of the team sharing to a network drive, as they do now, they would save to a shared Creative Cloud Files folder.

There are a couple of issues with this solution that I see so far.

1. Keywording is important and is a must, and bridge lacks a way for a team to share keyword lists. These are all on an individual level.
2. If we have 1TB worth of images on creative cloud files instead of on the network, then each user that has access to these images I believe will be forced to download all images directly to their drive right?

I've been looking at about 8 other possible DAM solutions, but none of them seem as integrated with other Adobe products and aren't as easy to use as simply using Adobe Create Cloud files with a shared folder.

What are you guys' thought, and what do you guys use for file management?

Comment: `:)` Best not not use acronyms without explaining what it stands for at least once `:)` If my edit was incorrect, please feel free to [edit](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/120184/edit) again.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't trust Adobe with DAM, they would get bored with it at some point and make changes to it that would break it terribly, they have a long and storied history of doing that. But I don't have a good recommendation either. I need something that is hosted in-house and can manage 3TB with an additional TB added each year and I think doing that in the cloud is impractical and wildly expensive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best File Management Practices when you have thousands of Files](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92246/best-file-management-practices-when-you-have-thousands-of-files)

Comment: a possible solution could be to sub-rent a DAM solution. I know a company that does rent its own DAM to its customers. Prices are then cheaper for the customer. win/win. Feel free to let me know if it's interesting for you.